# Confused about how/where to set a Xib's height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I have a custom view and xib. I use this custom view in one of my storyboard's controller views.

I have a use case where I want to be able to hide the custom view (and bring its height to zero). Right now, I set the height in the interface builder and set constraints to the superview's edges:

[image]

As you can see, I want its height to be `84` everywhere.

Now here is my custom view's class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class BannerView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initialize()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        initialize()
        contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }
    
    func initialize() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BannerView", bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
    
    func hide() {
        // Hide the view and set its height to zero here
    }

}
```

But, now I'm confused... should I also be setting a height constraint on the custom view when I load it into one of my storyboards? Or should its height be `84` everywhere and I shouldn't have to specify it any further?

Also, how would I hide the custom view and set its height to zero in the above `hide()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this... here's one.

Give the content of your xib constraints to make its height 84-pts. You haven't shown your xib's layout, but I'll assume you know how to do that.

Then, when you add `BannerView` to your main view (I'm guessing that's what you're doing), embed it in a Vertical `UIStackView` with these properties:

[image]

Now, when you set `bannerView.isHidden = true`, the stack view automatically removes it from the height calculations, resulting in the stack view having a height of Zero.

Setting `bannerView.isHidden = false` will then re-display the banner view along with its height.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the view's height to be 84 everywhere I think you should add a height constraint outlet and set the value 84.
Set the constraint value to 0 to hide the view (I highly suggest not to hide some view by doing this).

Comment: Would I set the height constraint in the Xib or where I include the custom view in a storyboard controller?